# Reconciling Multiple Blockchains?

Tags: blockchain

I'm playing around with the idea of a blockchain where both the proof-of-work and verification steps are NP-hard. It seems the NP-hard verification step can be resolved if you allow for multiple parallel blockchains with different sets of blocks in the head of each version. This of course creates another problem of trying to reconcile multiple blockchains in a secure manner.

The go-to proof-of-work method of reconciliation seems to be "take whichever chain has the most work in it," but is there anything out there already which allows for the reconciliation of the blocks without a loss of proof or transactional data?

Comment: Is this a thesis or a Stack Overflow question? This is really way too broad. Stack Overflow is really for questions where you've tried something, have some code, but can't quite get it to do what you want.

Comment: @tadman there don't appear to be any stack exchanges more applicable to the question and there are many approved questions relating to the theory of blockchains on stack overflow, there's even the tag for it.

Comment: This isn't the sort of thing you can quickly answer. Like any sync/reconciliation problem there's only complexity and edge cases.

Comment: @tadman I may have found a solution in the IOTA blockchain's concept of a `tangle`, but would definitely be interested in hearing any other solutions.